# How to change the display mode along with rotation animation?

Tags: css

In the following code, I want to have the square `shadow` appear and rotate at the same time, but the `display` does not change. Any help is very appreciated.

```css
#test {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 3px solid green;
  margin-top: 6px;
  left: 51.5%;
  background: red;
  border-radius: 50%
}
#shadow {
  position: absolute;
  border: 3px solid black;
  width: 120px;
  height: 120px;
  left: 50%;
  opacity: 0.2;
  display: none;
  -webkit-transition-property: -webkit-transform;
  -webkit-transition-duration: 1s;
  -moz-transition-property: -moz-transform;
  -moz-transition-duration: 1s;
  transition-property: transform;
  transition-duration: 1s;
}
#shadow:hover {
  display: block;
  -webkit-animation-name: rotate;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 2s;
  -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  -webkit-animation-timing-function: linear;
  -moz-animation-name: rotate;
  -moz-animation-duration: 2s;
  -moz-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  -moz-animation-timing-function: linear;
  animation-name: rotate;
  animation-duration: 2s;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  animation-timing-function: linear;
}
@-webkit-keyframes rotate {
  from {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  to {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}
@-moz-keyframes rotate {
  from {
    -moz-transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  to {
    -moz-transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}
@keyframes rotate {
  from {
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  to {
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="test"></div>
<div id="shadow"></div>
```

Comment: yes - just edited the question.

Answer (score 2):

It won't work like this because when you have it set to `display:none;` there's nothing to hover so the hover state never gets fired. You need to use only `opacity` to hide it rather than `display:none;`

```css
#test {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 3px solid green;
  margin-top: 6px;
  left: 51.5%;
  background: red;
  border-radius: 50%
}
#shadow {
  position: absolute;
  border: 3px solid black;
  width: 120px;
  height: 120px;
  left: 50%;
  opacity:0;
  -webkit-transition-property: -webkit-transform;
  -webkit-transition-duration: 1s;
  -moz-transition-property: -moz-transform;
  -moz-transition-duration: 1s;
  transition-property: transform;
  transition-duration: 1s;
}
#shadow:hover {
  opacity: 0.2;
  -webkit-animation-name: rotate;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 2s;
  -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  -webkit-animation-timing-function: linear;
  -moz-animation-name: rotate;
  -moz-animation-duration: 2s;
  -moz-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  -moz-animation-timing-function: linear;
  animation-name: rotate;
  animation-duration: 2s;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  animation-timing-function: linear;
}
@-webkit-keyframes rotate {
  from {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  to {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}
@-moz-keyframes rotate {
  from {
    -moz-transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  to {
    -moz-transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}
@keyframes rotate {
  from {
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  to {
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="test"></div>
<div id="shadow"></div>
```

Comment: @APADI1 - Is there way that I can have smoother rotation when I hover the mouse out?

Answer (score 1):

You can't hover a non-displayed element. There are a few solutions here, just as making the shadow a child of the test div.

Or, using a `+` CSS selector. In either case, the hover listener is on the visible element:

```css
#test {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 3px solid green;
  margin-top: 6px;
  left: 51.5%;
  background: red;
  border-radius: 50%
}
#shadow {
  position: absolute;
  border: 3px solid black;
  width: 120px;
  height: 120px;
  left: 50%;
  opacity: 0.2;
  display: none;
  -webkit-transition-property: -webkit-transform;
  -webkit-transition-duration: 1s;
  -moz-transition-property: -moz-transform;
  -moz-transition-duration: 1s;
  transition-property: transform;
  transition-duration: 1s;
}
#test:hover + #shadow {
  display: block;
  -webkit-animation-name: rotate;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 2s;
  -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  -webkit-animation-timing-function: linear;
  -moz-animation-name: rotate;
  -moz-animation-duration: 2s;
  -moz-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  -moz-animation-timing-function: linear;
  animation-name: rotate;
  animation-duration: 2s;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  animation-timing-function: linear;
}
@-webkit-keyframes rotate {
  from {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  to {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}
@-moz-keyframes rotate {
  from {
    -moz-transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  to {
    -moz-transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}
@keyframes rotate {
  from {
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  to {
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="test"></div>
<div id="shadow"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't animate "Display". If you want to fade in the box, have

```
display:block;
opacity:0;
```

and in your animations add

```
opacity:1;
```

this will fade in the box as it rotates.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot hover an element not displayed like #shadow (with display:none), but you have to hover #test and apply the css rule to the sibiling next to #test, that is #shadow (using + selector)

**#test:hover + #shadow**

```css
#test {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 3px solid green;
  margin-top: 6px;
  left: 51.5%;
  background: red;
  border-radius: 50%
}
#shadow {
  position: absolute;
  border: 3px solid black;
  width: 120px;
  height: 120px;
  left: 50%;
  opacity: 0.2;
  display: none;
  -webkit-transition-property: -webkit-transform;
  -webkit-transition-duration: 1s;
  -moz-transition-property: -moz-transform;
  -moz-transition-duration: 1s;
  transition-property: transform;
  transition-duration: 1s;
}
#test:hover + #shadow{
  display: block;
  -webkit-animation-name: rotate;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 2s;
  -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  -webkit-animation-timing-function: linear;
  -moz-animation-name: rotate;
  -moz-animation-duration: 2s;
  -moz-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  -moz-animation-timing-function: linear;
  animation-name: rotate;
  animation-duration: 2s;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  animation-timing-function: linear;
}
@-webkit-keyframes rotate {
  from {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  to {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}
@-moz-keyframes rotate {
  from {
    -moz-transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  to {
    -moz-transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}
@keyframes rotate {
  from {
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  to {
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="test"></div>
<div id="shadow"></div>
```